# Python sockets, two computers on same wifi

Tags: python, sockets, network-programming

I have two python (python 3) programs, one client and one server.

Client.py:

```
import socket
import time

clientsocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
clientsocket.connect(('192.168.0.18', 8087))

clientsocket.send(b'a')
time.sleep(0.05)
clientsocket.close()
```

Server.py:

```
import socket
import time

serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
serversocket.bind(('', 8087))
serversocket.listen(5)

connection, address = serversocket.accept()

b = connection.recv(1)
time.sleep(0.1)
serversocket.close()
connection.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)
connection.close()
print(b)
```

All it does is connecting a client and a server, and then sending the char 'a' from the client to the server. If I run both on them on the same computer, it works fine and the server prints 'a'. However, if I run the server on one computer and the client on another computer (both connected on the same wireless network), they get stuck on clientsocket.connect respectively serversocket.accept (and ultimately times out). The IP address is obtained by running ifconfig and pick the number after 'inet addr'.

How can I troubleshoot this problem? Is the firewall stopping my computer from taking connections?

I know there are other similar questions on stackoverflow, but none of them describe exactly this situation and the answers do not help me.

Comment: think the issue is in your server script and especially in this line of code: serversocket.bind(('', 8087)), what do you mean by this line?

Comment: @FadySaad: `bind(('',port))` means binding to any address. For IPv4 this would be the same as binding to `0.0.0.0`.

Comment: Are you sure that you have disabled all firewalls at the server side so that the system is actually reachable from outside on this specific port?

Comment: No I am not sure I have disabled all firewalls. Can you please tell me how to do that, or how to check if my firewall is blocking it? I am quite (very) new to network programming.

Comment: For sure the __server__ app is running on _192.168.0.18_ ?

Comment: @JonathanLindgren: Checking firewall status or disabling it depends on your operating system, installed software, maybe any network equipment etc. This is a question (i.e. not something which should be asked in a comment) by its own and would require you to provide all the information in the first place. It would also be off-topic here and more on-topic at superuser.com.